# no found Library richfaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I added to my project the `richfaces-api-3.3.1.GA.jar`, but the following error occurs when trying to set the xmls: rich, no library found for `"http://richfaces.org/rich" and xmlns: a4j = "Http://richfaces.org/a4j"`

My library

[image]

Comment: RichFaces 3.x works with JSF 1.2. If you want JSF 2 compatible version, then use RichFaces 4.x (preferably latest 4.5.17). Unrelated: jquery is inside RichFaces jar.

Comment: @VasilLukach this is not true (or maybe not in 100%). RF 3.3.3+ can be used with JSF 2.X. Read this: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20

Comment: Check if the jar files actually end up in your deployed running project

Comment: @EmilSierżęga I know it. Agree, my statement is not fully correct. It should be: for new project with JSF 2 can be used latest version of RichFaces.

Comment: The project ran, I took the classpath plugins and put it back, doing it also in the lib folder with the plugins

Comment: Thank you for all your help